# How do I control the message shown in the "Exception Thrown" window in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, exception, window

I have a custom exception type derived from System.Exception called ErrorCodeException. It has an "ErrorCode" property, that I'd like to display when debugging. The problem is, the window only shows the "Message" property of the base type.

[image]

The aim would be to display this ToString() function's return value:

```
public override string ToString()
{
   return $"Error code: {(int)ErrorCode} - {ErrorCode.ToString()} Message: {Message}";
}
```

The full declaration of my custom exception type:

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerDisplay("{ToString()}")]
public class ErrorCodeException : Exception
{
    public ErrorCode ErrorCode { get; private set; }

    public ErrorCodeException(ErrorCode errorCode, string message) : base(message)
    {
        this.ErrorCode = errorCode;
    }

    public ErrorCodeException(ErrorCode errorCode) : base()
    {
        this.ErrorCode = errorCode;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"Error code: {(int)ErrorCode} - {ErrorCode.ToString()} Message: {Message}";
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to assign the message property to a string you would like to show...

Comment: Thought about it, but I considered it a bit unprofessional, I mean, it generates redundant information (ErrorCode stored as a property and also as a string in another property). I'd like to only mix these props together when necessary, not from the beginning... But thank you!

Comment: What about a preprocessor directive?  You can assign it only in debug mode..

Comment: How did you declare your exception, can you share the code?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I've edited the main question with the full code :)

Comment: @alessio I don't really want to separate release - debug, it adds an extra level of complexity I currently simply cannot allow. But it could work, yes. Ultimately, I think (hope) there should be an easier solution for the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementing ToString() solves this, since it we'll be shown in the debug console, on complex objects.